# Items not displaying when pushed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am developing a rails app which so far works fine in production. However once I push to heroku, the following code:

```
<% @instructors.each do |i| %>

  <li><%= i.name %></li>
  <li><%= i.email %></li>
  <li><%= i.description %></li>

<% end %>
```

gives me the following error:

```
  Rendered /Users/ericabt1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericabt1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb (3.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericabt1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericabt1/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (48.1ms)
```

Any ideas why? I am new to Rails.

Comment: send us the full trace and not just 4 lines

Comment: Ok, what is a pull trace?

Comment: just run 'heroku logs -n 200' and it will bring the last 200 logs

Comment: My guess is that there's a view that depends on an item in the database that doesn't yet exist on Heroku. Does your app require seed data?

Comment: here is the trace. it's very long...

Comment: SO wont let me paste it all

Comment: 2014-02-11T23:53:44.432328+00:00 app[web.1]:     102:   <li><%= i.name %></li>
2014-02-11T23:53:44.432505+00:00 app[web.1]:     103:   <li><%= i.email %></li>
2014-02-11T23:53:44.432328+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "users".* FROM "users"):
2014-02-11T23:53:44.432505+00:00 app[web.1]:     101:
2014-02-11T23:53:44.432505+00:00 app[web.1]:      97: <!-- Instructors loaded from Database-->
2014-02-11T23:53:44.432328+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist

Comment: maybe that is enough to give you an idea

Comment: No I have not used any seed data.

Comment: Do I need to create a whole new database in Heroku? I thought the one that was created locally would get pushed up there too.

Comment: Fixed! You guys were right. A simple 'heroku run rake db:migrate' did the trick:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku doesn't have the data you have in your local app - hence the error

You should either create a Heroku db, or use `rake db:migrate` to create the databases you have in your local app

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the command `heroku run rake db:migrate`